# Change imported XSD package in WSDL2JAVA

Tags: maven, cxf, wsdl2java

SampleService.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:import location="sample.xsd" namespace="http://"project.company.com/sample/schema"/>
```

using WSDL2JAVA maven will generate a class SampleService.java and a POJO sample.java (from XSD). sample.java will be placed in com.company.project.sample.schema. 
I need to to customize the Sample.java location as well as its references of Sample in SampleService.java to same.

I'm using CXF Framework and maven to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Binding files to give custom location for java files generated by XSD schema